# java fx multiple selection with mouse like in excel

Tags: excel, javafx, mouse, selection

I am new to JavaFX and I have a GridPane with TextElements in it. I want to select multiple elements like in Excel with MousePressed on the first element and then drag the mouse down the row to another element and then release the mouse. After this all elements over which the mouse was moved, should be selected and be changed in some way (in my following example change the textcolor to blue). 
I searched a lot in the internet but I did not really find anything about how to do this, except, the setOnDragDetected-method with startFullDrag() in it. But it only changes the textcolor for the first element the mouse was pressed on. Can anybody tell my what I am missing?

```
public class Test extends Application {

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    primaryStage.setTitle("Test");
    Group root = new Group();

    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 600, 600);

    GridPane mainTable = new GridPane();
    mainTable.setGridLinesVisible(true);
    mainTable.prefHeightProperty().bind(scene.heightProperty());
    mainTable.prefWidthProperty().bind(scene.widthProperty());
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < 7; j++){
            StackPane entry = new StackPane();
            mainTable.add(entry, i, j); 
            Text tEntry = new Text();
            tEntry.setText("empty");
            entry.getChildren().add(tEntry);
        }
    }

    ObservableList <Node> entries = mainTable.getChildren();
    for (Node elem : entries){
        elem.setOnDragDetected(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
         @Override public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
          elem.startFullDrag(); 
          StackPane entry = (StackPane) elem;
          Text tEntry = (Text) entry.getChildren().get(0);
          tEntry.setFill(Color.BLUE);
         }
        });
    }

    int numCol = 6;
    for (int col = 0; col < numCol; col++){
        ColumnConstraints column1 = new ColumnConstraints();
        column1.setPercentWidth(100d/numCol);
        mainTable.getColumnConstraints().add(column1);
    }
    int numRow = 7;
    for (int row = 0; row < numRow; row++){
        RowConstraints row1 = new RowConstraints();
        row1.setPercentHeight(100d/numRow);
        mainTable.getRowConstraints().add(row1);
    }

    root.getChildren().add(mainTable);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

I would approach this as follows:

- Keep an observable collection of the selected texts (I use `Label`s in the example below). This will make it easy to find the selected ones (which I assume you will need at some point)
- Observe the selected texts and update a pseudoclass state. Use an external CSS file to change the color.
- Use an `onDragDetected()` handler to set the selection to that cell
- Use an `onMouseDragEntered` to extend the selection. You will need to keep track of where the selection was initiated.

As an aside, you can simplify your layout a little by using the properties of `GridPane` and applying them to your text elements. Also: be wary of using `getChildren()` on a `GridPane` when you have `gridLinesVisible` set to `true`. The children of the `GridPane` include the node representing the grid lines, so you can get unexpected results.

Here's an example of selectable labels in a grid pane:

```
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableSet;
import javafx.collections.SetChangeListener.Change;
import javafx.css.PseudoClass;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Priority;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class SelectableGridPane extends Application {

    private final ObservableSet<Label> selectedLabels =
            FXCollections.observableSet();


    private final int ROWS = 10 ;
    private final int COLS = 10 ;

    private final Label[][] labels = new Label[COLS][ROWS];

    private final PseudoClass SELECTED =
            PseudoClass.getPseudoClass("selected");

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        GridLocation mouseDownLoc = new GridLocation();
        GridPane grid = new GridPane();
        grid.setHgap(5);
        grid.setVgap(5);
        grid.setGridLinesVisible(true);

        for (int i = 0; i < COLS; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < ROWS; j++) {
                addLabel(grid, i, j, mouseDownLoc);
            }
        }

        selectedLabels.addListener((Change<? extends Label> change) -> {
            if (change.wasAdded()) {
                Label label = change.getElementAdded();
                label.pseudoClassStateChanged(SELECTED, true);
            } else if (change.wasRemoved()) {
                Label label = change.getElementRemoved();
                label.pseudoClassStateChanged(SELECTED, false);
            }
        });

        Scene scene = new Scene(grid, 800, 800);
        scene.getStylesheets().add("dragging-grid-pane.css");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private void addLabel(GridPane grid, int col, int row,
            GridLocation mouseDownLoc) {
        Label label = new Label("Cell ["+(col+1)+", "+(row+1)+"]");
        labels[col][row] = label ;

        grid.add(label, col, row);
        GridPane.setFillWidth(label, true);
        GridPane.setHgrow(label, Priority.ALWAYS);
        GridPane.setVgrow(label, Priority.ALWAYS);

        label.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        label.setMaxSize(Double.MAX_VALUE, Double.MAX_VALUE);


        label.setOnDragDetected(event -> {
            mouseDownLoc.x = col ;
            mouseDownLoc.y = row ;
            selectedLabels.clear();
            selectedLabels.add(label);
            label.startFullDrag();
        });

        label.setOnMouseDragEntered(event -> 
                recomputeSelection(mouseDownLoc, col, row));

    }

    private void recomputeSelection(GridLocation mouseDown, 
            int x, int y) {
        Set<Label> newSelection = new HashSet<>();
        int startX = Math.min(x,  mouseDown.x);
        int endX = Math.max(x, mouseDown.x);
        int startY = Math.min(y, mouseDown.y);
        int endY = Math.max(y, mouseDown.y);

        for (int j = startY; j <= endY; j++) {
            for (int i = startX; i <= endX; i++) {
                newSelection.add(labels[i][j]);
            }
        }

        // remove anything in selectedLabels 
        // that is not in newSelection:
        selectedLabels.retainAll(newSelection);

        // add everything from newSelection
        // to selectedLabels (will not duplicate):
        selectedLabels.addAll(newSelection);
    }

    private static class GridLocation {
        int x, y ;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

dragging-grid-pane.css:

```
.label:selected {
    -fx-background-color: -fx-background ;
    -fx-background: -fx-selection-bar ;
}
```

This is Java 8 code: it uses [CSS pseudo-classes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/css/PseudoClass.html). If you are forced to use Java 7, you will need to use plain css classes, which are tricky to manage:

```
    selectedLabels.addListener(new SetChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(Change<? extends Label> change) {
            if (change.wasAdded()) {
                Label label = change.getElementAdded();
                if (! label.getStyleClass().contains("selected")) {
                    label.getStyleClass().add("selected");
                }
            } else if (change.wasRemoved()) {
                Label label = change.getElementRemoved() ;
                label.getStyleClass().removeAll(Collections.singleton("selected"));
            }
        }
    });
```

The css file becomes

```
.label.selected {
    -fx-background-color: -fx-background ;
    -fx-background: -fx-selection-bar ;
}
```

(Note the `:` between `label` and `selected` was changed to a `.`: there are no spaces in the selector.)

You'll also need to change the other event handlers from lambda expressions to anonymous inner classes (or other class implementations).

Answer (score 0):

Your drag and drop listener is applied to every cell, and when the event starts it will only affect that cell, so that's why it's only changing the color of one cell.

Besides, for the drag to work you need to create a `Dragboard` instance with some content.

And while you are still dragging the mouse entering other cells, you will need to add another listener to those cells so they are possible targets of the drop.

Something like this:

```
ObservableList <Node> entries = mainTable.getChildren();
for (Node elem : entries){
    elem.setOnDragDetected(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
        @Override public void handle(MouseEvent e) {
            StackPane entry = (StackPane) elem;
            Dragboard db = entry.startDragAndDrop(TransferMode.ANY);
            ClipboardContent cb = new ClipboardContent();
            cb.put(DataFormat.PLAIN_TEXT, "");
            db.setContent(cb);
            Text tEntry = (Text) entry.getChildren().get(0);
            tEntry.setFill(Color.BLUE);
        }
    });
    elem.setOnDragOver(new EventHandler<DragEvent>() {
        @Override public void handle(DragEvent e) {
            e.acceptTransferModes(TransferMode.ANY);
            StackPane entry = (StackPane) elem;
            Text tEntry = (Text) entry.getChildren().get(0);
            tEntry.setFill(Color.BLUE);
        }
    });
}
```

Also have a look at this [post](http://blog.ngopal.com.np/2013/09/07/listcell-animation-listview-javafx/), that uses a `TableView` containter instead of a `GrigPane` to allow range selection.

Comment: I only use the "drag-and-drop gesture" (initiated by `startDragAndDrop`) for actual data transfer. For this use case, a `startFullDrag` should be enough.